# listener not calling while clicking on item in android

Tags: android

I have two class (not activities), and one interface with single method with parameter.
In first class, I'm sending data in parameter.

```
 private void sendProviderData(General provider) {
        Singleton.getInstance().setProviderId(provider.getId());
        Singleton.getInstance().setProviderIcon(provider.getIcon());
        Singleton.getInstance().setProviderName(provider.getName());

//Listener
        ResultListener resultListener;
        resultListener = this;
        resultListener.onActivityResult(CommonUtils.PICK_PROVIDER_CODE, CommonUtils.RESULT_OKAY);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

**Second class(I just implemented listener, any other things I have to do?), I want to get acknowledge that listener is called, so that I can get data:**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode) {
        showLog("???");
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OKAY) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case PICK_PROVIDER_CODE:
        showLog("worked!");
                    /*    providerId = data.getLongExtra(PROVIDER_ID, 0);
            inputBillProvider.setText(data.getStringExtra(PROVIDER_NAME));
            selected = data.getStringExtra(PROVIDER_NAME);
            setProviderValidation(selected);*/
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First class

```
private ResultListener resultListener;
----
---
public void setResultListener(ResultListener listener) {
   this.resultListener = listener;
}

public void sendProviderData(General provider) {
        Singleton.getInstance().setProviderId(provider.getId());
        Singleton.getInstance().setProviderIcon(provider.getIcon());
        Singleton.getInstance().setProviderName(provider.getName());
        resultListener.onActivityResult(CommonUtils.PICK_PROVIDER_CODE, CommonUtils.RESULT_OKAY);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

in Second class, let's say you have FirstClass instance name `firstInstance`, you need to set Second class as the listener. after creating the First class instance. So you can get the response

```
FirstClass firstInstance = new FirstClass();
firstInstance.setResultListener(this)
firstInstance.sendProviderData(provider);
.......
....
..
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode) {
        showLog("???");
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OKAY) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case PICK_PROVIDER_CODE:
        showLog("worked!");
                    /*    providerId = data.getLongExtra(PROVIDER_ID, 0);
            inputBillProvider.setText(data.getStringExtra(PROVIDER_NAME));
            selected = data.getStringExtra(PROVIDER_NAME);
            setProviderValidation(selected);*/
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Really really thnks for helping! Doubt: Should I have to implement interface any of the class? or should I remove?

Comment: The second class should implement the interface

Comment: Is this line necessary?: firstInstance.sendProviderData(provider);

Comment: Because, when user click on first class dialog recycler item, that time only I have to do something in second class, otherwise not

Comment: No. if you are calling sendProviderData from some where else. thats fine.

Comment: Thank you very very much my dear, you're really helpful and intelligent person.